# How to set cookie?

Tags: f#, httprequest, f#-data

I have the following code, which uses http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html, to login a website and get some files. However, each page has a piece of jQuery script to set a cookie - `$.cookie("Authenticated", 14313432);`. My code has to mimic the jQuery script to set the `cc` too. Otherwise the authentication will fail. How to do it using F# Data: HTTP Utilities?

```
let cc = CookieContainer()
let h = Http.RequestString(url, httpMethod = "GET", cookieContainer = cc, headers = headers) // embedded jQuery will set the cookie
let body = HttpRequestBody.FormValues ["UserName", "xxx"; "Password", "ppp"]
Http.RequestString(url, body=body, httpMethod="POST", cookieContainer=cc, headers = ...
let page = Http.RequestString(....) // embedded jQuery script will set the cookie with different value
let page2 = Http.RequestString(....) // embedded jQuery script will set the cookie with different value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you don't know how to insert `"Authenticated", 14313432` as a cookie but you found how to use a `CookieContainer` right?

Well the [`CookieContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa2f921c(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a .net class contiaining [`Cookie`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie(v=vs.110).aspx) Objects, so this should do the trick:

```
let cc = CookieContainer()
let cookie = Cookie ("Authenticated", "14313432")
cc.Add cookie
// the rest of your code
```